# Stubborn +24 in the topbar that won't go away

Tags: bug, status-completed, top-bar, achievements-dialog, caching

I currently have this in my topbar:

[image]

I click it. The list shows up and the indicator is gone. Yay!

Then I load another page. And the indicator is back. Is this related in some way to the recent Redis upgrade?

It's now a +39 (from upvotes on this and other posts), and it still won't go away.

Comment: Same problem. And votes for today are not displayed at all. I got some upvotes and notifications but they are not dispayed at all. Only displayed that I earned a badge.

Comment: All smells of a broken Redis caching tier. Mine has a stuck notification as well.

Comment: At least you're getting reputation. My indicator is not moving! And I wrote lots of great answers, too...

Comment: Yep, I just got an upvote, and it doesn't show in the top bar as a green notification, and isn't reflected in the list either.

Comment: FYI [Repeated reputation notification for same upvote](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/265326/456814) same problem?

Comment: @Cupcake Yes, same problem. It's network-wide.

Comment: Gone. Working now.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This was indeed related to the Redis upgrade, and should now be resolved.

Comment: Why no diamond? :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Heh, one of these days I'll pester someone to add that ;)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Actually, I'll pretend that it's intentional so I can get the +2 rep when my edit gets approved to add the `status-completed` tag!

Comment: @ShaneMadden - SE employees are upvoted insanely.

Comment: But, waaait, if you have no diamond, how can you add [status-completed] ?!?!

Comment: @AzizShaikh Of course, I understand that he suggested adding a tag. But it was **mod-only** tag. But his edit was submitted.

Comment: @nicael a valid point

Comment: @nicael he is marked as employee in the database, just without a diamond.